# How to add a string right before the last record

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, vba

I have the following code. Technically, what I'm doing is getting a list of names. So I want to display them like:

**Maria, John, and Michael,**

However, the code below produces this:

**Maria, John, Michael,**

I need to insert the word **"and"** before the last record. Please help. I'm getting stuck.

```
SQL = "Select firstname from Distributionlist where program1 = " & Me.Program & " order by firstname"
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL)
Do While Not RS.EOF
f1 = f1 & RS("firstname") & ","
RS.MoveNext
Loop
RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
msgbox(f1)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. One simple way would be checking with a first and last record.

something like:

```
Dim I as long
i = 1
Do While Not RS.EOF
    if (i <=1) then 
        f1 = nz(rs("firstname"),"")
    elseif i = rs.recordcount then
        f1 = f1 & " and " & RS("firstname")
    else
        f1 = f1 & ", " & RS("firstname")
    end if
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Hi there, first of all. thank  you very much for your support and your help. However, after running the code, it only display the last record only. It doesn't display anything else. Other thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I take the previous comment back. It worked great. I would like to add that I had to add "I = I + 1" in between the RS.MoveNext and the Loop lines. Therefore, the I value keeps increasing. Other than that. It worked great. Thank you so much. You're the best krish.